# Query for a result within a result using Logic Apps

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, crm, azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON document within CosmosDB that looks like this

```
 { 
   "id":"1234-11111-22222-2222"
   "Feedbacks": [
       { "id": "abc"
       }
                ]
}
```

I would like to first find all the documents where the ids are >15 and then loop over and find all the feedbacks that are associated with this result. How would I do this using the LogicApp? I have an idea and this is what I have done so far:

[image]

[image]

I am not sure if I have to perform another query? if so, what would this be?

Select c.Feedbacks from ...?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you query the feedback directly?

Comment: Hi because I need to first find all the ids are greater than 15, and then within this set I need to do something do these feedback ids. Is there a way to find all that are greater than 15 then locate all the feedback ids? I need to perform a loop update to these

Comment: ultimately because I must push this first result to CRM, then I must find all query 1 results feedbacks and update these accordingly

Comment: Just ad I know about logic, we can not do that. Do you think about using Data Factory Data Flow? It can be more easier and also support trigger runing.

Comment: Oh I see, Logic App cannot loop over the first query result and extract data from it?

Comment: yeah, because you need get the all the data which id>15 and  update the Feedback ids. Am I right? I think Data Factory is more suitable for you.

Comment: Hi @Lynnette, I  post it as answer. Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Just ad I know about logic, we can not do that. Your really purpose is that get the all the data which id>15 and update the Feedback ids.

I think [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) is more suitable for you.

You could using [Data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) to achieve that. Create Cosmos DB as Source, using [Mapping data flow transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-transformation-overview) to update the Feedback ids.

Ref tutorial: [Copy and transform data in Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db)

Update:

We can do a nested query like: for each (document d array) // iterate over documents array do for each (feedback f in d.feedback) // iterate over feedback array in each document do something with f ... done done

Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: I believe I just have to do a nested for each query

Comment: @Lynnette Something like for each Current Item.Feedbacks?

Comment: Right you do a nested query like: for each (document d array) // iterate over documents array

do

    for each (feedback f in d.feedback) // iterate over feedback array in each document

    do

        something with f ...

    done

done

Comment: Aha, congratulations! You could get result you want! Does it mean your problem is solved now? Or what's next step we need to figure out?

Comment: No far from solved. I need to query over the feedback.id array and update all these ids etc. I am working this now

Comment: Hi @Lynnette, did you get any progresses now?

Comment: Hi Leon, no I have posted a few questions as I am still trying to get the LogicApp to work

Comment: The point is  how to update the each feedbacks after the data filter. We could wait for some days if other people can give more better suggestions or workarounds. BTW, if you have enough time, just try it with Data Factory.